# Directory to directory copy in ansible remote host in not working

Tags: linux, ansible, redhat

I am trying to copy Directory of remote host from one location to another.

My playbook code is

```yaml
- name: copy folder to another folder

      copy: 
    
        src: /home/smuser/namitha/ajay 

        dest: /home/smuser/priyanka/

        remote_src: yes

        directory_mode: yes
```

I am getting the error output as

```
Remote copy does not support recursive copy of directory
```

I think I can done it with copy module itself

Answer (score 0):

i done it with command module

- name: Move foo to bar
  command: mv /home/scmuser/namitha/ajay /home/scmuser/priyanka/
  but i really want to know how do with copy module

Answer (score 0):

1. directory_mode is to set mode (permissions) and it is not about telling ansible to do a recursive copy, so "yes" is not a reasonable value for it.
2. According to https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html "remote_src supports recursive copying as of version 2.8.". Do you use at least version 2.8 of ansible?